# Oracle SQL LIKE Operator not working with values less than 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use the LIKE operator with a column name which contains values less than 1..
For example:

- -0.009123
- 1.9504
- 0.240921

The LIKE statement returns a value for any value which is greater than 0 so for example 1.95 but NOT for any value that begins with 0. or -0.

My Oracle SQL Looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM planet WHERE location LIKE '0.240921%'` doesn't work

`SELECT * FROM planet WHERE location LIKE '1.9577821%'` works

The data type for this column in Oracle is: `NUMBER (15, 10)`

Why does the statement above NOT work for values that start with 0 e.g. 0.20012, -0.029115, 0.25009 etc etc

Comment: Why are you trying to match **numbers** with some **string** pattern?

Comment: Greater than 0 and not starting with 0, I presume, is called *absolute value is greater than or equal to 1*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`location` is a number and `LIKE` compares strings so you are not actually comparing `location` you are implicitly comparing `TO_CHAR(location)` to `'0.240921%'`.

You will probably find that the leading `0` is being omitted and need to use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM planet WHERE location LIKE '.240921%'
```

Or explicitly format the number as a string:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   planet
WHERE  TO_CHAR(location, 'fm99990.0000000000') LIKE '0.240921%'
```

or, don't compare on strings:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   planet
WHERE  location >= 0.240921
AND    location <  0.240922
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o-VNePIv)

Comment: That makes so much sense!! One quick question.. Since the leading 0 are being omitted and doing .2456 will work. What if the value im searching for is not 0.2456 but 0.02456. How will i need to update my select statement to capture that value?

Comment: @CsharpStudent If you were going to use strings then `LIKE '.02456%'` or a better solution would probably be to use the third or second queries (the third being preferred as you are comparing numerically rather than comparing alphabetically and it can use an index on the location column).

Comment: @MT0 is there a way to make it work using the LIKE statement..

Comment: @CsharpStudent As said in the answer, you can use `TO_CHAR(location, 'fm99990.0000000000') LIKE '0.240921%'`. If you want to use `LIKE` with an implicit conversion then, also as mentioned in the answer, you will just have to omit the leading `0` from the integer part. Other than those two options it is unclear what else you would expect.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a more intuitive query handling numbers as numbers. Looking for a decimal number that starts with `0.240921` is the same as looking for a number in the [0.240921, 0.240922) interval, so:

```
SELECT *
FROM planet
WHERE location >= 0.240921 AND location < 0.240922
```